# Twitter4j 3.0 for Android, uploadImage

Tags: android, image, post, upload, twitter4j

is anyone start using Twitter4j version 3.0 for Android integration?

I am trying to using this lib within my Android project, and accomplish "UploadImage" feature, but most of the information I found is related to lower version. Can anyone give me some suggestions, please? Very appreciate.